# Getting iOS outlets wired in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, ios, outlet

I'm new to developing in iOS and successfully ran through a tutorial on how to create and connect outlets in a Mac OSX Cocoa App.  However, when I try to follow the same process for my iPhone app, I keep hitting walls... (Apologies for the lengthy example- please bear with)

**Project A:**

In xCode:

1. Create new Mac OSX Cocoa Application
2. Create a new class

   `SimpleViewController : NSObject`

---

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SimpleViewController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *aField;
    IBOutlet NSButton *aButton;
}

@end
```

In Interface Builder:

1. File > Read class files
2. Drag
   `SimpleViewController` from my library
   into the main.nib
3. Ctl-drag from
   `SimpleViewController` to view
   elements to connect my outlets

Everything above works great. 
Now for the same thing in an iPhone app:

**Project B:**

In XCode:

1. Create new iPhone OS Window-Based Application
2. Create a new class

   `SimpleViewController : UIViewController`

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class NSTextField;
@class NSButton;

@interface EmbedComplexViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *aField;
    IBOutlet NSButton *aButton;
}

@end
```

(Notice my view controller is now an extension of `UIViewController`, not `NSObject`.  Also, this time I need to use forward class declarations for my outlet classes.  Not a problem, but is this necessary?)

In Interface Builder:

1. File > Read class files
2. Drag
   `SimpleViewController` from my library
   into the main.nib
3. Ctl-drag from
   `SimpleViewController` to `view`
   elements - BUT now I can't see any of my declared outlet member variables.  Instead, the only outlet option I have is 'view'

What more do I need to do to have my declared outlets show up?

Thanks- Yarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS development, we use `UIButton` and `UITextField` and etc, (see the iphone developer documentation).

And no, you don't need to forward declare those classes (it made you since they weren't included in UIKit